# How to assign a decorator to a method of each child class of a parent class, in Python

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I have a Parent class and many subclasses extend it. I overwrite a method of parent class at each subclass. But I don't want to lose the decorator that the method overridden. Here is an example:

```py
class Parent:
  @decorator
  def a_method(self):
    print('Parent class a_method')

class Sub1(Parent):
  def a_method(self):
    print('Sub1 class a_method')

class Sub2(Parent):
  def a_method(self):
    print('Sub2 class a_method')
  
class Sub3(Parent):
  def a_method(self):
    print('Sub3 class a_method')

s1 = Sub1()
s1.a_method() # doesn't run @decorator
```

I need the decorator to be reflected in the `a_method` of each subclass. In other words, I want to run the same logic before and after `a_method` invoked and don't want to write it again and again in each subclass. How to achieve this? And what would be the best way to realize it? This doesn't need to be a decorator but It would be nice and more cleaner.

Thanks!

Comment: One possibility: change the name of the method in the child classes (let's call it `b_method`), and add `self.b_method()` inside `Parent.a_method`.

Comment: Thanks! But as far as I understand, that doesn't let me run the same logic *before* and *after* each invocation of `a_method` of subclass?

Comment: Okay, I understood wrong and it works well! But this time I need to wrap a try catch to make sure that each Sub class has `b_method`

Comment: You could put a `b_method()` implementation in the parent class that raises an error (or does something else appropriate) if a particular child class failed to override it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically a `metaclass` would be perhaps appropriate here, in order to decorate the relevant method inside the `__new__` method during class creation.

```
def decorator(f):
    def wrapper(*args):
        print('decorator fired!!!')
        return f(*args)

    return wrapper


class MetaClass(type):
    def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, attrs):
        if 'a_method' in attrs:
            attrs['a_method'] = decorator(attrs['a_method'])
        return type.__new__(cls, clsname, bases, attrs)


class Parent(metaclass=MetaClass):
    def a_method(self):
        print('Parent class a_method')


class Sub1(Parent):
    def a_method(self):
        print('Sub1 class a_method')

    def k_method(self):
        print('Sub1 class k_method')


p1 = Parent()
p1.a_method()
print("-------------------------------")
s1 = Sub1()
s1.a_method()

# decorator fired!!!
# Parent class a_method
# -------------------------------
# decorator fired!!!
# Sub1 class a_method
```